# Increase number of visitors to a question (without bounty)

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I need a tricky idea to increase the number of visitors to my questions on Super User. Sometimes I ask a question on SU where the answer is really important to me but after a week or more just has 10 to 30 visitors and has no answer; how can I increase the number of visitors to such questions?

P.S: I think of a way that your question always suggest by google to other people who search about. but it need a tricky way to force google crawler and spider to show your question as a top 3.

Comment: And.. what's wrong with giving a bounty? If people can answer it, they will - since thats a good way to get rep. If its a hard question, bounty is a good way to get more people interested in it.

Answer (score 17):

In addition to bounty, see this section of [the /faq](https://superuser.com/faq#bounty) --

> ### What if I don't get a good answer?
>
> In order to get good answers, you have to put some effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.

Comment: What if it's someone else's question and you can't ask your own as it's a duplicate and you can't edit it as you don't have enough rep/the OP isn't around anymore?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the question, which will bump it back to the recent activity list (the default list that comes up when you navigate to superuser.com).  This should put it back out there for anyone watching.  Note that your question will be bumped in this way whenever anyone answers or edits their answers as well.

Comment: I also do this but not so effective.